# What is the voltage at the inverting input terminal of an op-amp, with respect to ground?

Tags: operational-amplifier, homework

I am currently writing a lab report for an introductory lab in electrical engineering on the subject of op-amps. One question that I'm stuck at is

> With the op-amp operating in its linear regime, what voltage would you expect at 
>   the negative (inverting) input terminal, with respect to ground? How does this 
>   compare with your measurement of \$V_n\$?

I think the goal is to test the idealness of an inverting op-amp with the data that I have here:
[image: Op-amp idealness]

The op-amp circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUDIYp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Supply voltages:
\$V_{cc+}=15.664\$ V
\$V_{cc-}=-15.143\$ V

I was taught that the golden rule of an ideal inverting op-amp is \$V_n=V_p\$. But what is \$V_p\$? It can't be the input voltage because of the golden rule. **How do I answer those questions with the given data?**

Comment: Was there a schematic with the question? It would be very useful.

Comment: @Transistor Yes, I just added it.

Comment: "But what is Vp?"  By inspection, voltage Vp--the voltage at the op amp's non-inverting input--is zero volts. _(NB: Ground potential is zero volts, and the op amp's non-inverting input is connected directly to ground potential.)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the datasheet, Vp-Vn = Vio (input offset voltage), which should be close to ~3mV as the spec says. Ideally, you may think it should be zero.

Ip and In is the input bias current, Iib, which should be ~30pA. Your measurement seems to high, but your equipment may not go that sensitive.